# Adding a class to a button breaks Bootstrap popover

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, popover, bootstrap-5, bootstrap-popover

I use a `sanitize: false` configures popover with `Bootstrap 5`:

```
<button type="button" 
        class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" 
        data-bs-container="body" 
        data-bs-toggle="popover" 
        title="register"
        data-bs-content="${popoverContent()}">
         <i class="fas fa-server">
</button>
```

js part:

```
let popoverContent = function ( ) {
    let buttonsDiv = document.createElement("div")
    let delButton = document.createElement("button");
    delButton.textContent = 'delete';
    buttonsDiv.appendChild(delButton);
    return buttonsDiv.innerHTML;
}
```

which looks like this:

[image]

if I now change the js code to:

```
let popoverContent = function ( ) {
    let buttonsDiv = document.createElement("div")
    let delButton = document.createElement("button");
    delButton.textContent = 'delete';
    delButton.classList.add('btn');
    buttonsDiv.appendChild(delButton);
    return buttonsDiv.innerHTML;
}
```

I get this:

[image]

Why did not just the button get another `class="btn"` attribute?

*update*:
This is what the HTML looks in the console after the `classList.add('btn')`:

```
<button type="button" 
        class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" 
        data-bs-container="body" 
        data-bs-toggle="popover" 
        data-bs-placement="left" 
        title="" 
        data-bs-content="<button class=" btn"="" 
                                 data-bs-original-title="register on server">delete</button>
```

obviously `class=" btn"=""` should be `class="btn"` - but where is my error?

*update:*
I added a fiddle to show the problem: https://jsfiddle.net/93gLyha2/12/ - also watch how the button changes it size when uncommenting the 2nd or 3rd line in the js part of the fiddle

Comment: Why are you dumping the button element into a div just to dig it out again? Why not just return the button element?

Comment: Also, did you notice that the blue buttons are apparently modified by your script? Or is that not part of the issue? Please put all your code into a single functioning snippet using the editor. Load Bootstrap via CDN.

Comment: I added a fiddle to show the display in even simpler way.